# Trouble selecting contents of hidden span, in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a span...

```
<span class="tActivityId">1234</span>
```

...whose contents I can successfully get at:

```
//Button click handler for the dynamically added buttons
function TicketSelect(clicked_id)
{
    var $target = $("#" + clicked_id);  
    //I don't like parent().parent either, but could't get closest to work
    var activityid = $target.parent().parent().parent().find(".tActivityId").text();
    ...
}
```

However when I amend the span so that is hidden (which I need to):

```
<span class="tActivityId, hidden">1234</span>
```

and the related .hidden css.

```
/*Intended for hidden spans*/
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

The selector no longer works, and I get "" rather than the original "1234" when the span was not hidden.

Various answers on SP state that to get the contents of a hidden span you should use .text() which I already am. Am I missing something?

***Update***
I was the comma in the css that caused the issue - thanks Zee in the comments.

Comment: why the comma ? `<span class="tActivityId hidden">1234</span>`?

Comment: Remove comma separator from `class="tActivityId, hidden"` . So that class="tActivityId hidden"

Comment: Why the `.parent().parent().parent()`? Can you not use `closest` or `parents`?

Comment: If possible better to illustrate this issue with help of http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Thenks zee - it was the pesky comma. For some reason I keep adding those! As you were the first post as answer for the points. Thanks jeepOnline - missed by 1m :)

Comment: @putvande - I agree I should be able to. I had tried  var foo = $(this).closest('tr').find('span.tActivityId').text(); but couldn't get it to work - maybe it was the comma as well...

Comment: Any comments as to why the downvotes would be most welcome. I'll assume its the parent().parent() .This place really hates learners some times.

Comment: Not a downvoter but, I think the reason is that the issue was basically a result of a  'comma'. But I understand that there are other scopes to this questions. Like the `parent` selection. Try to post the `html` using jsfiddle.net . That can help in finding a solution.

Comment: Fair enough @RejithRKrishnan - I'll assume any jquery question without a jsfiddle will attract downvoters :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though `tActivityId, hidden` the comma was your issue and

```
<span class="tActivityId">1234</span>
```

fixes it,

```
//Button click handler for the dynamically added buttons
function TicketSelect(clicked_id) {
    var $target = $("#" + clicked_id);  
    var activityid = $target.parents().eq(2).find(".tActivityId").text();
}
```

The above code can help you remove some of the unnecessary `parent()`.

If you post the HTML of the main parent we might be able to help you further.

Comment: Thanks Rejith - not come across .eq and it does tidy it up a little. I didn't like the multiple parent calls either which I'm guessing was why this Q attracted the downvoters.

Comment: @Fetchezlavache So `$(this).closest('tr').find('span.tActivityId').text();` is working now, isn't it?

Comment: Alss not. Or $target.closest('tr').find('span.tActivityId').text()
Unfortunately I'm having trouble getting a fiddle to work as so much of the content is dynamically generated..

Comment: @Fetchezlavache try using the html from source perhaps.